# Line feed for single tag with mutiline value in Element tree

Tags: python, xml, internet-explorer, web, elementtree

I have used Element Tree in my python script to generate the XML file with my own tags input.

I need set multiline value to a single tag in the XML file. for example,

```
 Prj_Name = "GetComp"
 Prj_Desc = """ Level : 3
                Author : Jhon
                Date   : 12 May 13
                Details  : .......
                ..................
                .................. """
 top = Element('ProjectInfo')
 child = SubElement(top, 'Name')
 child.text = Prj_Name
 child = SubElement(top, 'Description')
 child.text = Prj_Desc
 indent(top)                        # this function will format the XML tags
 tree = ET.ElementTree(top)
 tree.write("MyXML.xml")
```

In this XML 'Description' tag contains mutilline string. if we open the file in Notepad++, we able see the description tag properly as below,

```
 <ProjectInfo>
     <Name>CompInfo</Name>
     <Description> Level : 3
     Author : Jhon
     Date   : 12 May 13
     Details  : .......
     ..................
     .................. </Description>
  </ProjectInfo>
```

If we open the xml file in IE(internet explorer), the multiline string 'Description' tags displayed in a single line as below,

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  -<ProjectInfo>
       <Name>GetComp</Name>
       <Description> Level : 3 Author : Jhon Date : 12    May 13 Details : ....... .................. .................. </Description>          
   </ProjectInfo>
```

How to we add line feed in Element tree for Element with multiline value?

Answer (score 2):

To briefly lecture. XML spacing, newlines, tabs and the like should not be what you rely on for styling. XML should be a vessel to transport information and be able to handle constant re-formatting without losing its significance.

That being said, you probably want to at least encode your newlines with `&#10;` so that they are transferred independent on how you have it set up in a notepad file.

Comment: Hi.. Shay...  am new to XML, could you please tell me how to encode the string with &#10; in python

Comment: i tried with &#10; but not working... can you pls suggest some other way

Comment: `Prj_Desc.replace('\r\n', '&#10;').replace('\n', ''&#10;')` Takes care of Windows and Linux style newlines.  I would also recommend lower case or camel case variable names (i.e., `project_description`, `proj_description`, 'projDescription', 'projectDescription')

Comment: Do you just mean it's not showing the newline in Internet Explorer?

Comment: You have to replace the `'&#10;'` with `'\n'` on a read of the serialized XML.